# Bind RPZ setup issue

Tags: bind

I've tried all possible howto's and failed, therefore need your help -

I'm trying to setup DNS (bind) only for RPZ proposes.
Config is clean and simple (removed all other options and want to run on defaults - easier to debug):

```
/etc/named.conf:
options {
response-policy { "rpz.zone"; };
};

zone "rpz.zone" IN {
type master;
file "/etc/named/rpz.db";
};
```

There's no prob with named.conf syntax.
rpz.db is a file from provider so syntax is correct also.
Bind is listening and responding on lo and eth0 interfaces (no other interfaces in box).

When I'm trying to query for one of rpz domains I am getting:

```
# dig baddomain.test.com @127.0.0.1
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

In named.log I've found:

```
query-errors: debug 1: client <client IP>: query failed (SERVFAIL) for baddomain.test.com/IN/A at query.c:6569
```

BUT if I'll add - only for testing proposes - example domain *outside rpz*, there's no problem with query.

```
/etc/named.conf:
zone "test.com" IN {
type master;
file "/etc/named/test.db";
};
```

I'll skip test.db content and dig output as it's working for that particular/testing domain - problem is only within rpz domains.

You're my only hope. Thanks!

Comment: You say there is no problem with the config syntax, but `response=policy {rpz.zone};` is invalid in multiple ways. (Actually all of the config included has issues)

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad - typing from my smartphone so there are little typos (s/response=policy/response-policy plus missing ";" at the end) but on box all is correct. Somewhere there's a logic issue or I am missing some options.

Comment: `named-checkconf -zj` is all happy? It's hard to judge what the problem might be when the configuration in the question is full of little issues that supposedly do not exist in the actual environment.

Comment: I know Håkan - really sorry for that. Corrected config in 1st post. Can't do copy/paste...
Yes, named-checkconf -zj is happy - all zones loaded successfully.

Comment: Please don't waste peoples time with sloppy editing. Post config files exactly as written and if necessary, wait until you are sitting at a real keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Check your syntax for your [Response Policy Zone Configuration](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/rpz.html). You should be more careful! As in all configuration files, one character can count. You could have these corrected by using any tutorial:

- The statement is `response-policy`, not `response=policy`.
- You must have `zone` before the zone name.

You should have:

```
options {
  response-policy { zone "rpz.zone"; };
};

zone "rpz.zone" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/named/rpz.db";
};
```

The Connection timeout doesn't mean that your server is not responding: as you can see in the `named.log`, BIND gets the query but is not able to respond due to `SERVFAIL`. Therefore `dig` never gets its answer on UDP and a timeout occurs.

Comment: Thanks. Looks all is ok with syntax. Triple checked. Somehow bind can't see rpz cname section.
Btw is it normal behavior?:
in simpletest.zone I have simpletest.com domain,
named-checkzone simpletest.com simpletest.zone returns OK but in same time, named-checkzone wtf.com simpletest.zone also returns OK even wtf.com does not exist in simpletest.zone.
I'm lost :(

Comment: This answer was based on the configuration you provided. How could I guess you had it right while it was definitely wrong in your question?

Comment: Hey Esa. You're right it was a bit confusing. I wrote syntax is correct but in same time I made few typos during rewriting. Sorry for that!
Thank you for effort!

Comment: No problem. It was your first post. Now you know better how to answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Mystery SOLVED:
My box does not have access to internet. Bind is contacting/resolving auth srv mentioned in rpz zone so it need to access internet directly or trough other dns forwarders.
Thanks All for help!